# Magento 2.2.6 - Attributes Issue with Store View and product created by REST

Tags: attributes, rest-api, store-view

I have a product created in M2 and I create a new product attributes, and when we make an update with c# app using REST Call. 
In this case the new added attributes are empty in edit product page with "Store View" configured on "All Store Views". 
But when I switch to "Default Stotre View" we get values in those fields.
The problem is when I delete this product and I recreate it with REST Call, I haven't those empty attributes.(that's work correctly)

I don't know if that's normal or not in Magento or how to fix that?

this is some snapshot to explain my issue:

In catalog product page those fields have values
[image]

when I edit this product on all Store Views mode, the new attributes are empty
[image]

now I switch to Default  Store View
[image]

And now in Default Store View, we have our values
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it would be important to know, to which endpoint exactly you are sending the request.

But if I understand you correctly, we might have had a similar issue.

The Product overview in the backend shows the values of the defined default store view (under Stores -> All Stores) which can be confusing, because the product edit page initially shows the values of the default scope (which is not equal to the default store view).

Magento has a fallback mechanism for these values from default scope -> website scope -> store group scope -> store view scope

If you send something to `/rest/V1/products` it will be saved in the default store view (tbh., not 100% sure on this one). This is also shown in the overview, but it's not the default (global) scope, which is shown initially in the product edit page.

If you want to save something in the default (global) scope for a product, send it to `/rest/all/V1/products`. This will save the value(s) in the default (global) scope.

If you want to edit / save a value for a specific store view (mostly used for translations), you send it to `/rest/<store_view_code>/V1/products`

So in conclusion, sending something to the rest api without the "**all**" keyword or a store code is mostly just confusing